# why css variables override another file's css variable?

Tags: html, css, css-variables

When I define a variable in various CSS files, and include these files in my HTML file, then it overrides the previous variable.
Why is it happening?

*Let's say that I have*

**test1.css**

```
:root {
    --size-of-font: 5rem;
 }
.logo{
    font-size: var(--size-of-font);
}
```

**test2.css**

```
:root {
--size-of-font: 1.2rem;
}
.outer {
    font-size: var(--size-of-font);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**test.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">

<div class="outer">
    <h1 class="logo">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
     <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem 
          ipsum quia..."<br>
          "There is no one who loves pain 
          itself..."
     </p>
</div>
```

Comment: In CSS the latest style rule applied to an element is used, unless the original rule has a greater specificity. So if you apply two style sheets and they both target the same element, the last one loaded will be the one that is applied.

Comment: Do you not just want the outer-size-font variable in your .outer { }? because then you won't have thie font-size issue if that is the case.

Comment: just to go off of gavgrif's comment: `:root` is more generic then `.outer`, thus `.outer` stylings get applied :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs: What does "generic" mean here?

Comment: @BoltClock `:root` can apply to anything, kinda like.. targetting `div` with CSS. it's a more generic specification, as opposed to classes and IDs. Classes and IDs are less generic and more specific

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs :root apply to only root not to anything

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs: That doesn't really mean anything to CSS, though. .outer still uses the custom property defined in :root - since that's the only place it is ever defined.

Comment: @TemaniAfif ah true dat ^^ haha

Comment: @BoltClock I let you answer this one ;)

Comment: @BoltClock sorry, not getting what you mean :)

Comment: @Temani Afif: SazooCat's answer is satisfactory. You have two competing :root CSS rules across two stylesheets, so one overrides the other and all other rules that depend on --size-of-font are affected accordingly.

Comment: no. both has same variable size-of-font

Comment: Please note that CSS variables are not that different from other CSS properties. First of all, `:root` simply means the element at the root of the document, that is, the `html` element. Other elements then inherit the variables via the normal CSS rules.

Comment: @BoltClock I know but I am pretty sure that he's thinking that the first var() is evaluated to the custom property defined before it in the CSS file and will not consider the one after defined after

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ah, you mean the OP thinks that after the first assignment of the var to a property, the property value can't change any more, even if the var does? That's possible, but then maybe you should post that as an answer, pointing out their mistake.

Comment: @Mr Lister: I posted an answer.

Comment: @MrLister I also posted one :p

Answer (score 4):

CSS = **Cascading** Style Sheets... this means the sequence of definition matters, the most recent and more specific takes precedence.
If you switched test1 and test2 over in your html you'd get a different result because the variable is defined as the more recent value.

I recommend you use a different variable name for your different .css files if you require them to not share this value.

Comment: not always the most recent - later rules may still not apply with case use of `!important` or if the previous CSS rules have a higher specificity value

Answer (score 1):

When you include both stylesheets, all of their rules are combined into one single stylesheet. This means that you introduce a conflict in two `:root` CSS rules with the same custom property declaration:

```
:root {
  --size-of-font: 5rem;
}

:root {
  --size-of-font: 1.2rem;
}
```

Cascade resolution means that the specified value of the `--size-of-font` custom property is 1.2rem, not 5rem. Simply, the second declaration overrides the first as both rules have identical selectors.

This value of 1.2rem is then applied to both uses of `var(--size-of-font)`, in `.logo` and `.outer`, again because two stylesheets combine to form one. `.logo` does not only see the `--size-of-font` in its own stylesheet; it sees whatever is resolved by the cascade, **taking all declarations into account**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will overwrite. If I have two classes having the same name like:

test1.css contains

```
.text-color{
    color:red;
}
```

test2.css contains

```
.text-color{
    color:blue
}
```

and apply them in sequence

test1.css
test2.css

it will apply the CSS which is in test2.css. It takes the latest CSS if the class names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here we need to consider two things: How *custom properties* works and how they are evaluated using `var()`.

1. The first part is trivial because custom property behave the same as any other property. From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#using-variables) we can read:

> Custom properties **are ordinary properties**, so they can be declared on any element, are resolved with **the normal inheritance and cascade rules**, can be made conditional with @media and other conditional rules, can be used in HTML’s style attribute, can be read or set using the CSSOM, etc.

Considering this, the last custom property defined in your case will override the first one:

```
:root {
    --size-of-font: 5rem;
 }
.logo{
    font-size: var(--size-of-font);
}

:root {
  --size-of-font: 1.2rem; /* This one will win !*/
}
.outer {
    font-size: var(--size-of-font);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
```

2. When using `var()` we need to also consider some rules like defined in the same specification:

> To ***substitute a var()*** in a property’s value:
>
> 1. If the custom property named by the first argument to the var()
>      function is animation-tainted, and the var() function is being used in
>      the animation property or one of its longhands, treat the custom
>      property as having its initial value for the rest of this algorithm.
> 2. If the value of the custom property named by the first argument to the
>      var() function is anything but the initial value, replace the var()
>      function by the value of the corresponding custom property. Otherwise,
> 3. if the var() function has a fallback value as its second argument,
>      replace the var() function by the fallback value. If there are any
>      var() references in the fallback, substitute them as well.
> 4. Otherwise, the property containing the var() function is invalid at
>      computed-value time

In our situation, we will consider the (2) because `.logo` will inherit the custom property defined inside `:root` with its value `1.2rem`  (not an initial value).

In other words, the evaluation of a custom property doesn't consider the order of their appearance in the CSS file. It considers the value of the custom property that is resolved as an ordinary property.

---

Here another useful question where you can get more details and more examples: [CSS scoped custom property ignored when used to calc var in outer scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015737/css-scoped-custom-property-ignored-when-used-to-calc-var-in-outer-scope/52015817#52015817)

Comment: Note that custom properties don't work the same as other properties in all respects. You cannot use `var(..)` on ordinary properties; e.g. `{color: #444; background: var(color);}` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to CSS for websites, within a CSS file, `<style>` tag, or inside an HTML tag. CSS files will always have precedence over any other CSS format. `<style>` tags only have precedence over CSS tags in HTML, which are at the bottom.

Here's a visual

1. CSS Files (Comes first)
2. `<style>` (Cannot override CSS files but can override HTML inline)
3. HTML inline styles (least important)