# Is it possible to reference a :root css variable within another :root variable?

Tags: css, css-variables

```
:root {
    --foo: #fff;
    --bar: --foo;
}
```

A use case would be - I allow a primary colour to be set and be re-used within other variables.

I cant seem to find any information on this and i'm starting to think its not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply like this

```
:root {
    --foo: #fff;
    --bar: var(--foo);
}
```

You can also have a more complex case:

```
:root {
    --foo: #fff;
    --bar:3px solid var(--foo); /* Define a border using the --foo color*/
}
```

But you should notice that such thing is *useless* in most of the cases because you are evaluating a variables inside `:root` using another one. If you change the main variable later, nothing will happen.

Related to get more details: [CSS scoped custom property ignored when used to calculate variable in outer scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52015737/8620333)

Comment: @MikeHague you may check the update before accepting as I susoect you will be using this syntax for a particular purpose and you will get surprised when it won't work

Comment: It's working as i wanted thanks! Im actually using a computed Vue function with these and the above works well and updates as i wanted. Thanks again